# undefined method `lane' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I have 2 files:

Fastfile

group.rb

Fastfile

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

fastlane_version '2.116.0'

default_platform :ios

import "fastfiles/group.rb"

platform :ios do
lane :pr_build do
    set_enterprise_app_id
  end
end
```

group.rb

```
lane :set_enterprise_app_id do
  update_app_ids(
    app_id: BUNDLE_ID_ENTERPRISE,
    shared_extension_id: BUNDLE_ID_ENTERPRISE_SHAREEXTENSION
  )
  update_app_group(APP_GROUP_ENTERPRISE)
end
```

But get error on my CI:
[!] undefined method `lane' for main:Object

I tried next in group.rb

```
platform :iOS do
    lane :set_enterprise_app_id do
      update_app_ids(
      app_id: BUNDLE_ID_ENTERPRISE,
      shared_extension_id: BUNDLE_ID_ENTERPRISE_SHAREEXTENSION
    )
    update_app_group(APP_GROUP_ENTERPRISE)
    end
end
```

But get next error:
[!] undefined method `platform' for main:Object

Comment: Just at a guess (I'm unfamiliar with `fastlane`), maybe you're using the wrong type of [import](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/Fastfile/#load-own-actions-from-external-folder)?

Comment: We do something very similar, how are you calling fastlane on the `Fastfile`? Is the `Fastfile` inside of a `fastlane` directory and you are calling it via `fastlane set_enterprise_app_id`?

Comment: My Fastfile in fastlane directory. And fastfiles folder there too

Comment: @TomLord I don't know I use standard import in Fastfile. You can offer me any solution?